# Django - how to filter a model in a foreign key field?

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have two models for categories, list of categories for all users *(each unique)* and list of connections between user and category.

**# category/models.py**

```
class CategoryList(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, max_length=60, verbose_name='Category name')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class UserCategories(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryList, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE, verbose_name='User's categories')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE, verbose_name='User')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.category.name}'
```

Also I have transactions

**# transactions/models.py**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE, verbose_name='Transaction from')
    payment_amount = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, verbose_name='Payment amount')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Date')
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Time')
    category = models.ForeignKey(UserCategories, null=True, on_delete=models.deletion.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Category')
    organization = models.TextField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Organization')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Transaction discription')
```

I have the next issue:

I'm using **DRF** to do **CRUD** operations with transactions, and when I'm trying to add a transaction *(it selects the current authorised user)* or update it, I get all the categories in the field

```
category = models. ForeignKey(UserCategories...)
```

and that's not what I want. As far as I can tell, selecting a model in a foreign language is similar to selecting a model in English.ForeignKey *(**`UserCategories.objects.all()`**)*, but that's not what I want... I need something like filtration; while creating or updating transactions, it has to show me only the list of categories for my current user, not all! I need a final result like **"category = models."**
**`ForeignKey(UserCategories.objects.filter(user=user))`**, but I'm not sure (and didn't find an answer in the docs) how to filter out only categories for my current user.

**Djoser** is also used for user registration and authentication. This is mandatory. I tried to add a **ManyToMany** field for my custom user, but to make a category choice work, I need to add a special serializer and add it to the base **"user_create"** function like **`category = CategorySerializer(many=True)`**, but I can't. Djoser is in my venv, and it's not the best solution to make some changes in someone else's lib.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in Django filtering with the foreign key, you need to pass the full object of the related model you can pass in views.py like this...

```
get_category = CategoryList.objects.get(id=id)

UserCategories.objects.filter(category=get_category)


# ------------------- OR ------------------


get_category = CategoryList.objects.get(id=id)
UserCategories.objects.filter(category__id=get_category.id)
```

Comment: I don't even have anything in categories/views.py. The issue appears when DRF call's my TransactionAPICreate class based on generics.CreateAPIView, it has serializer class TransactionSerializer where i can't make inline field like:
fields = ('user', 'payment_amount', 'date', 'time', 'category <- some filter to show only current user's categories', 'organization', 'description')
You can check and understand project structure in my git repo - https://github.com/Fakemrx/xone-test-project.git